# Chained selects - where to place script

Tags: jquery

This question is more about where the correct place is for my jquery ajax script..

I have 4 drop-downs. The first is active, the other 3 are inactive. So to start, I have the following:

jQuery within my `<head>` tags:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sel1').change(function() {
           var m = $(this).attr("value");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: "a=getSel2&m="+m+"",
                    success: function(txt){
                        $("#div_sel2").html( txt );
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

page1.php:

```html
Selection 1:
<select id="sel1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

Selection 2:
<div id="div_sel2"></div>

Selection 3:
<div id="div_sel3"></div>

Selection 4:
<div id="div_sel4"></div>
```

The HTML and jQuery reside in `page1.php`. The select onchange triggers the AJAX request for `ajax.php` and function `getSel2`. The result fills div `div_sel2`.

Here is where I am not sure. The result of `getSel2` is another drop-down similar to `sel1`. Obviously with its only options and `id="sel2"`. I need to have this select also trigger another AJAX request for `getSel3` which will then fill `div_sel3`. BUT if I place this AJAX code within `page1.php`, it does not work. If I place that code within my `getSel2` result, it also does not work.

What is the correct way to do a page that contains AJAX calls, which then needs to trigger additional AJAX calls after its filled a div?

**SOLUTION:**
I went with this plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Comment: You need to use the on() delegation method to account for things that are being added to the page via Ajax. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Do you mean like this:
$('#sel1').change(function() {
changes to:
$("#sel1").on("change", function() {

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle so that we can work on the interaction?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/APzQC/2/

Comment: I dont know how to get jsfiddle to talk to an external page..
http://we-value-you.co.za/ajaxx.php?a=getSel2&m=1
http://we-value-you.co.za/ajaxx.php?a=getSel3&m=1